# How to prevent sorting layers from disappearing on export and importing

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity version - 5.0.1f1

So my buddy and I are in the process of putting some stuff in the Unity Asset Store and our current situation is that we are working on the same project on our personal computers but he is doing level design, character design and prefabs and I am working on code and we both have the same hierarchy setup in our projects.

What ends up happening is that when he is done he will package up what he did and send it over to me and when I open the package I will see the scene just all kinds off visually messed up in its layering and this is because when I look at my gameobjects I see that the sorting layer says .  We have tried doing this with a fresh project as well as a project where the assets over lap and update to the newest changes and we still get the same result.

Now this is a big problem for us because we are going to have demo scenes to help explain some of the assets we are offering but this really does frighten us as this is not fair for someone to go through and this just doesn't seem right at all.  We have bought from the Asset Store as well and never had this issue, it was just import to project and done.

I have done some research on this to see any work around but the only thing I found was taking a file called "tagmanager.asset" from the project that is being exported and placing it in the project that you are importing it to.  Now for myself I can deal with this issue of moving files, but selling this... and having the user have to do an extra step is just bad and I was wondering if anyone can shed some light on what to do.